# Setting SQL variables in Prepared statments in PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Situation:** I have a junction table with the columns `testFK`, `questionFK`, and `ordinal`.

```
    testFK | questionFK | ordinal
       2         14          1
       2         15          2
       2         16          3
      _____________________________
 NEW   2         17          4
```

I want to add a new row to the table with `testFK = 2` and `questionFK = 17`, however, I want the `ordinal` to be automatically generated based on what is already in the table. Since the highest ordinal is 3, then I want `SQL` to automatically generate 4.

**I've tried:**

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('
        SET @QOrdinal = (SELECT MAX(ordinal) FROM junc_test_question WHERE testFK = ?);

        INSERT 
        INTO junc_test_question
        (junc_test_question.testFK, junc_test_question.questionFK, junc_test_question.ordinal)
        VALUES (?, ?, @QOrdinal);
    ');


    $stmt->bind_param('iii', $this->testID, $this->testID, $question_id);
    //var_dump($stmt);
    if($stmt->execute()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

This works if I hard code the `ordinal` in, but I can't seem to make `SQL` do it on it's own.

Any input is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
The error I'm getting

```
Fatal error:  Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in \classes\Test.php on line 91
```

So I'm assuming the `SQL` isn't correct.

Comment: what is the formula of generating ordinal ?

Comment: While the answers below should work, I'd like to know why your original approach doesn't. Also, as an aside, use table aliases. They will declutter your queries!

Comment: i have seen the update and gave you a solution

Comment: @Strawberry he wants to increment it based on testfk value

Comment: @Strawberry can you explain more or give a sample code?

Comment: @Strawberry I want to be sure they are exactly what they should be.

Comment: What happens if you delete row 2, say?

Comment: @Strawberry Then Question 15 would no longer be associated with Test 2 and the ordinals would read 1,3.

Comment: Then I guess my solution below is fine.

Comment: @Strawberry There seems to be a misunderstanding. That's what WOULD happen, not what I WANT to happen. I want the ordinals to read 1,2 in that case.

Comment: In which case you simply would not store this information, but instead calculate it on the fly. In fact, since you have a presentation layer, just handle the display logic there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IN THE CONTEXT OF THE OPs MOST RECENT COMMENT, THE SOLUTIONS PRESENTED BELOW ARE NOT APPROPRIATE.

If you use MyISAM table type and define a primary key in which the auto increment column is the 2nd one, then [MyISAM automatically calculates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) the the increments grouped by the 1st field (see MyISAM notes in the linked document):

> For MyISAM tables, you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary
>   column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value
>   for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as
>   MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix. This is
>   useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.

So, you can simply define the table as follows - although, in practice, I'm not sure that I'd store this ordinal at all:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(testFK INT NOT NULL
,ordinal INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
,questionFK INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(testFK,ordinal)
) ENGINE = MYISAM;

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(2,1,14),          
(2,2,15),          
(2,3,16);

INSERT INTO my_table (testFK,questionFK) VALUES
(2,17);

SELECT * FROM my_table;

+--------+---------+------------+
| testFK | ordinal | questionFK |
+--------+---------+------------+
|      2 |       1 |         14 |
|      2 |       2 |         15 |
|      2 |       3 |         16 |
|      2 |       4 |         17 |
+--------+---------+------------+
```

Alternatively, you can do something along these lines (simplified) - but I'd never seriously advocate this solution:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (testFK,questionFK,ordinal) 
SELECT 2,18,MAX(ordinal+1) FROM my_table;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+--------+---------+------------+
| testFK | ordinal | questionFK |
+--------+---------+------------+
|      2 |       1 |         14 |
|      2 |       2 |         15 |
|      2 |       3 |         16 |
|      2 |       4 |         17 |
|      2 |       5 |         18 |
+--------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: It's a Junction Table, so these associations will be deleted and changed frequently. This doesn't account for that at all.

Comment: @Guy That seems to contradict what you said above.

Comment: I like this, since it relies on a built-in feature of a table engine

Comment: I got your alternative solution working. Thanks a lot for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO junc_test_question (testFK, questionFK, ordinal)
VALUES (2, 17, (select * from (select ordinal+1 from junc_test_question order by ordinal desc limit 1) as p) );
```

For the next ordinal query same table for max value and add 1 to it.

Comment: Someone has down voted the answer but this solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO junc_test_question (testFK, questionFK, ordinal)
VALUES (?, ?, (
  select MAX(ordinal)+1 from  (select * from junc_test_question ) as rftable where testFK=?
) );
```

this is my answer.

Comment: @ArefAnafgeh I'm getting an error when I try this.
You can't specify target table 'junc_test_question' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @Guy did my answer helper you?